# Simple JSON deserialisation for dummies

Tags: vb.net, json, serialization

Trying to deserialise the following json returned from a web source:

```
{
    "cards": [
    {
        "high": "8.27", 
        "volume": 5, 
        "percent_change": "0.00", 
        "name": "Wurmcoil engine", 
        "url": "http://blacklotusproject.com/cards/Scars+of+Mirrodin/Wurmcoil+Engine/", 
        "price": "6.81", 
        "set_code": "SOM", 
        "average": "5.67", 
        "change": "0.00", 
        "low": "1.12"}], 
        "currency": "USD"
    }
```

I am using json.net with visual basic, new to both of them, especially the object oriented portions of vb. I would just like to extract the 'price' variable.
I have set up a class as such:

```
Public Class Card
    Public high As String
    Public volume As String
    Public percent_change As String
    Public name As String
    Public url As String
    Public price As String
    Public set_code As String
    Public average As String
    Public change As String
    Public low As String
End Class
```

The code I am currently using is:

```
Public Sub parse_json(url As String)
    Dim blp_json As String = ""
    Dim wClient As New WebClient
    wClient.Proxy = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
    blp_json = wClient.DownloadString(url)
    MessageBox.Show(blp_json)
    Dim card_1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Card)(blp_json)
    PriceTextBox.Text = card_1.price
    TextBox1.AppendText(card_1.ToString)
    TextBox1.AppendText(blp_json)

End Sub
```

Just trying many different things to get a hang of it, not really sure what I am doing. I presume my Card class is incorrect as 'price' appears to be nested in cards:[{...}]

I don't really know about deserialising json at all, and much less about how to do it /properly/ in vb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` for JSON deserialization. Your example is slightly complicated by the fact that `cards` contains an array of JSON objects. This is indicated by the "[" and "]". This example code will show you how to process it regardless of whether `cards` is an array or not. You may wish to ignore the `Else` if you are sure that there will always be an array in `cards`

Make sure that you have included a reference to System.Web.Extensions in your project and...

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
```

and then...

```
Dim MySerializer As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim dictResult As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = MySerializer.Deserialize(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(blp_json)

Dim dictCard As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

If dictResult.ContainsKey("cards") Then

    If TypeOf dictResult("cards") Is ArrayList Then

        Dim arrResult As ArrayList = DirectCast(dictResult("cards"), ArrayList)

        For Each arrCardRecord In arrResult

            dictCard = DirectCast(arrCardRecord, Dictionary(Of String, Object))

            If dictCard.ContainsKey("price") Then Console.WriteLine(dictCard("price"))

        Next
    Else
        dictCard = DirectCast(dictResult("cards"), Dictionary(Of String, Object))
        If dictCard.ContainsKey("price") Then Console.WriteLine(dictCard("price"))
    End If

End If
```

Comment: To reference `System.Web.Extensions` make sure you're using the full .Net framework and no just the pared down `Client` one. Then you can add a reference to `System.Web.Extensions` into your project. You are most welcome.